# Azure ML Internal Server Error and 404 Error

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Azure ML pipeline run failed with status message ServiceError: InternalServerError.
[image: Internal server error]

404 error when viewing executionlogs.txt, stderrlogs.txt, and stdoutlogs.txt.
[image: 404 error]

A pipeline run completed the day before. No changes were made between these runs.
[image: Pipeline runs]

Compute cluster properties:

- VM size: Standard_D3_v2 (4 cores, 14 GB RAM, 200 GB disk)
- Processing unit: CPU - General purpose
- OS type: Linux
- Location: East US

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete and create the endpoint again and this should work.

Also, for Error 404, make sure that URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**The root cause of the issue:**

Time-based retention policy was set on the storage account level. This immutability policy prevented Azure Machine Learning from writing log files to the workspaceblobstore, hence the 404 error when viewing any of the log file followed by InternalServerError.
[image: version-level time-based retention policy]

**Solution:**

Allow protected writes to append blobs

[image: allow protected writes]